# Ubuntu shell utility to check if the modifier key is pressed down

Tags: shell, ubuntu, key, utility, modifier

Is there any shell utility in Ubuntu which can define if the modifier key (Ctrl, Shift, Super, Alt) is pressed down on the moment when i run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `showkey`.  Manpage is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/showkey.1.html).

Comment: `showkey` works fine, but you've got to use it with `-a` argument because without, - it requires the root privileges.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `xev` utility which prints information about X events (including keypress events). It's available if you're running X11.